# Is there a stack exchange for design?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know there are websites such as behance and dribbble but I was wondering if there is a stack exchange dedicated to design, any kind of design or specific kinds.

Comment: There's a graphic design site. You can find it if you search for "design" in the community list in the top right of the screen. I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: [Take a look for yourself](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name)

Comment: You may ask specific design questions at SE Software Engineering.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ dribbble and behance are graphic design sites; I don't think he wants software architecture design sites.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, I misunderstood :-P

Comment: [ux.se] and [graphicdesign.se]

Answer (score 3):

There is [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), which covers exactly what you want.

You can see a list of all sites by visiting https://stackexchange.com/sites or by clicking the Stack Exchange logo on the topbar of any site and scrolling down (or searching in the search bar at the top of the list of SE communities).